# Retain files during a git-merge to avoid deleting them in the process

Tags: git

As the situation demands, i have a branching strategy, which have 5 branches.

**master,
dev,
qa,
staging &
prod**

[image]

The 4 branches (expect the master), all started from the master branch. so initially, all of the 4 branches have the same files. Now, to start work a feature, i create a feature branch from `dev` branch. And i remove all the unnecessary files and kept only the files that i need. (e.g. i had 10 files, i removed 7 so i just 3 files on my feature branch). The problem is that when i merge the feature branch back to the `dev` branch, it removes all the files and keeps only the 3 files from my feature branch.

The same delete for files happens when i merge the `dev to QA, staging and prod`.

I am trying to avoid deletion of files, rather just update the files that have changed or added newly. How can i achieve this?

Comment: The solution is trivial: don't delete files you don't want deleted. Git assumes that if you deleted file `F`, you *meant* for it to go away, so the merge will make it go away!

Comment: What @torek said, plus: look into sparse checkout if the extra files in the worktree are bothersome.  Also: you can do your mergeback `--no-commit` and `git checkout --ours` any files you didn't want deleted.

Comment: @torek, so i guess thats the only solution to my problem. but that limits us to deploying/pushing only the changes files and not the whole source. @jthill, not sure what `--no-commit` and `git checkout --ours`, have to do with the file deletion during git merger

Comment: What @jthill means is that if you run `git merge --no-commit`, Git will still combine both sets of changes by deleting the deleted files, but before you commit the result, you can *restore* those files, overriding Git's automatic combining. But you will have to remember to do that every time.

Comment: Actually, you don't. After you've merged back once, no deletions appear in the merged histories.  Try it.  You do have to remember when you switch directions, but it's easy to deal with.

Comment: @jthill: oops, yes, I meant "with every first merge of the branch", but phrased it badly.

Comment: @torek  @jthill  not sure if i am following here, but here is what i am trying. `dev` branch have 10 files, created a `feature` branch and deleted 9 files. Switched to dev, and ran  `git merge --no-commit feature1` .. This deletes the files. It doesn't give an option to `git checkout --ours` or --theirs

Comment: It's quite manual. There's no merge commit *yet*, so now you can `git checkout HEAD -- <all nine files>`. Then commit, and now a later `git merge feature1` does not delete 9 files, since you have said that the correct result of merging `feature1`'s changes includes keeping those 9 files. (More precisely, the merge created a new *merge base*, so future merges don't "see" the removals.)

Comment: Wait, what?  *"so i guess thats the only solution to my problem. **but that limits us to deploying/pushing only the changes files and not the whole source.**"*  Why?  What problem do you foresee from deploying an unchanged file?

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger add unchanged files increases the deployment time and may cause failure due to conditions set by the saas provider. I am dealing with salesforce here

Comment: Well, you might want to check what salesforce recommends as a solution to deltify what you send them, then.  The solution of telling git to delete everything else from the branch is highly unusual, and I would hope it's not their recommended approach

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger Well may be you dont understand here...

Comment: It might help if you explain what's really going on here. Please be concrete: why should only some changes be merged back?  What specific good do the other changes, the deletions here, actually achieve? I don't understand either, because you're asking about your preferred solution to a problem you don't state.

Comment: I will update the question